# Holonomic modules and Holonomic functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, differential-equations, d-modules, algebraic-combinatorics

Let 
$$f_{d}(h):=\sum_{k=1}^{d}(-1)^k\binom{d-1}{k-1}\prod_{i=1}^{d}G((i-k)h) . $$

I have proved that $ F(x):=\sum_{d=1}f_{d}\frac{x^{d}}{d!}\in \mathbb{C}(h)[[x]]$ is holonomic and arrive at a bound on the order of the differential equation it should satisfy. I have no idea about the bound of the degree of the differential equation it satisfies.

Recently I came across on the topic of Holonomic modules. I have seen that these are modules over the Weyl algebra and there is a notion of dimension of modules. I have not read in-depth or definition of dimension in this context. The literature seems huge.

So I have the following questions

1) In the book "The concrete Tetrahedron" there is a definition of the holonomic function. How can I relate this to holonomic modules? Any introductory reference or hint is very useful.

2) I was flicking through the pages of the book "A primer to algebraic D-modules" I came across the notion of dimension and multiplicity of the module is this any help to give a bound on the order and degree of the differential equation of the holonomic function $F(x)$.